# Tomcat Clustering with Session Replication

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

Trying to implement tomcat cluster with session replication using two tomcat instances. below are the things which I have done. I am using tomcat 8.0.33

server.xml having below details

> 

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="8"> 

    <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
        address="228.0.0.4"
        port="45564" frequency="500"
        dropTime="3000"/>           

        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">             
            <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>               
        </Sender>        

        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
        address="auto" port="4002" autoBind="100"
        selectorTimeout="5000" maxThreads="6"/>                     

        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>          
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>                       

    </Channel>

     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" />    
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener" />     

</Cluster>
```

for another tomcat I have changed port to 4001. both the tomcat instances are on same server.

context.xml

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
```

I am able to access web application but session is getting expired

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: Its done, I have changed channelSendOptions from 8 to 6 and also changes has been made into code too Its working fine.